# projected surface normal vector onto xy plane

Tags: c++, geometry, vector-graphics

i have a plane whose equation is ax+by-z+d=0. hence, its normal vector (a,b-1). Now, i need to project my vector to xy plane in order to compute direction of it from the North axis (i guess it is Y axis in here. please help me to get projected vector. thank you.

Comment: It's not clear to me. Do you want to project to the World XY plane?
X: (1,0,0)
Y: (0,1,0)
Z:(0,0,1)
or do you want to project to an arbitrary plane?

Comment: @ santiagoIT=> i have a 3D plane and its equation is ax+by-z+d=0. for this plane, i computed the normal vector. i guess that normal vector is in 3d. now, i need to project that to the world XY plane. it is better, if i can project the vector to the arbitrary plane which is passing through a point of my plane. But, i guess i can get similar result even if i work with world XY plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). Finding the direction the plane is facing is pretty easy that way.

```
// generic code, actual code depends on your engine.
// BasePlane.GetNormal() would equal to (0,0,1) for the X/Y plane
float dir = YourPlane.GetNormal().Dot(BasePlane.GetNormal());
```

If it equals to `1`, your plane faces the same direction as the plane you're testing against. If it equals to `-1`, it's facing the the plane. Equalling to `0` would mean the plane stands orthogonal to the tested plane. Hope this helps.

Comment: @ xeo;thank you for the response. I am sorry to confuse you. But, actually i need to get the projected normal vector. i do not know how to project my 3d vector (i.e; a,b,-1) to xy plane. then, it become a 2D vector. Hope, it is clear now. [g_niro]